# Solving Complex Numbers Equation

Tags: complex-numbers

]

I need to solve an equation of complex numbers, couldn't do it so I watched a video and couldn't understand how he got from this, Z is a complex number: $$(Z-1)^2-(\overline Z-1)^2$$
to this : $$(Z-1+\overline Z -1)(Z-1-\overline Z+1)$$

It'll be really helpful if you can point me on how he did this, thank you.

Comment: Use identity $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

Comment: What's with the close votes?

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$.